# Tomcat still does not show directory list even if I enabled it in conf/web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

So I already set listings to true and tomcat still does not show my directory.
I also restarted the server numerous times but still same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've edited the web.xml in TOMCAT_HOME/conf

Below is a scenario I have come across which doesn't show the directory listing

You've got a  `<servlet-mapping>` in your individual webapp's web.xml with a

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

This goes off to execute the servlet in your webapp and not the DefaultServlet in the TOMCAT_HOME/conf, when you request for http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/, and hence it does not fire the directory listing

Comment: but i don't have a xml yet for my webapp. just pure js and jsp files.

Comment: you dont have a WEB-INF/web.xml in your webapp?

Comment: Yup. Based from what I read, it should be fine because the conf/web.xml is the global right? I am using resin before trying to transfer to tomcat. So... there's no really web.xml in resin.

Comment: @ice3d: are you using the URL including the trailing slash? http://localhost:8080/mywebapp /

Comment: Yes. I can access files using localhost:8080/mywebapp/home.jsp but cannot access directory using localhost:8080/mywebapp/